# Coldfusion Excel cell values 28D and 28F lost during export to excel

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am facing a weird issue with an excel export. I am exporting my products to excel using cfspreadsheet.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" 
    overwrite="true" 
    query="DownloadProducts">
```

When I open excel, the columns with values `28D` and `28F` are replaced by just numbers like `28` and `29`. The D and F alphabets are lost.

[image: Excel - Actual Result]

I did a cfdump and the values are correct there:

[image: CFDump raw query result]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553674/cfspreadsheet-alphanumeric-values-ending-in-d  explains the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your help!